Why can't I animate position in aframe ar.js?
I am building a project with vue3, aframe and ar.js. So far it works great, even the rotation animation works:
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" cursor='rayOrigin: mouse' raycaster='near: 0; far: 50000'
                arjs='sourceType: webcam; videoTexture: true; debugUIEnabled: false;'
                renderer='antialias: true; alpha: true' embedded>
                <a-camera :gps-new-camera="'gpsMinDistance:' + gpsMinDistance + ';'" :near="near" :far="far"
                    look-controls-enabled='false' arjs-device-orientation-controls='smoothingFactor:0.1'
                    rotation-reader></a-camera>
                <a-entity v-for="(md, idx) in mds" :key="idx" :gltf-model="md.properties.model3DGltf"
                    :gps-new-entity-place="'latitude: ' + Number(latitude) + '; longitude:' +                                               Number(longitude) + ';'"
                    :scale="md.properties.scale == undefined ? '5 5 5' : md.properties.scale" 
:position= "mindset.properties.position == undefined ? '0 0 0' : md.properties.position"
                    :rotation="md.properties.rotation == undefined ? '0 0 0' : md.properties.rotation"
                   animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 10000"
                    :id="md.id"
                    clicker></a-entity>    
            </a-scene>

but if instead it is a position animation, all objects are not to be shown in screen, it doesn't work.
animation="property: position; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true"

At first I thought it must be an ar.js thing, since "(some of) the position" is created by gps-new-entity-place. But the definition of position (not animated) works, I mean the object is placed following the gps-place and eg the height of the position. The problem is the animation.
Any ideas?

Alright, I fixed it. It works if you animate the object3D property like so: animation="property: object3D.position.y; to: 115; loop: true; dur:1000"
